# Using jsf 2.2, Weld 2.3.5 with JBOSS 6 EAP

Tags: jsf, jboss, cdi

I'm trying to use the last version of libs in my project. But Jboss EAP 6.2 already have some old libs, so i created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml and move to 'WEB-INF/' folder. See the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" />
          <module name="org.jboss.weld.core"/>
        </exclusions>       
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In my pom.xml i added some libs that i need:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The jboss should ignore jsf 1.2 and weld provided and use my libs in pom.xml, right ? But when i start the jboss i got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.faces.util.Util.isCdiOneOneOrGreater()Z
```

So i changed my jboss-deployment-structure.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
           <subsystem name="jsf-impl"/>
           <subsystem name="weld"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now, console don't show error but when i try access my jsf page i got 404 page not found.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to EAP7?

Comment: Unhappy, no. I should continue in EAP 6 but use some new tecnologies.